# What is the difference between interrupting escalation event and error event?

Tags: events, bpmn, escalation

As I understand escalation event is used to inform parent process. If escalation event is interrupting, it means that regular flow will be ignored and a new flow will be handled. But it is similar to error event. What is the difference?

Comment: I have just created a proposal for a new community that only deals with business process modeling because I noticed that many business-related questions around process modeling are lost amongst the software-focussed questions around modeling apps in the stackexchange community. Feel free to have a look and I am looking forward to your inputs regarding the community's future ! : https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/121238/business-process-modeling?referrer=IU7kc0WmXuuHw8-vDBM9aw2

Answer (score 2):

You are right, escalation events are used to communicate from a subprocess to a parent process. Unlike an error, an escalation event is, by default, non critical and execution continues at the location of throwing.

Answer (score 1):

The difference in **notation** is that

- `Error events` are always interrupting (as the name suggests), either as an `Event Sub-process` start event or a `Boundary event` of a `Sub-process`.
- `Escalation events` are by default non-interrupting but they can also be modelled as interrupting events. They can, just like `Error events` be `Event Sub-process` start events or `Boundary events`.

The more important **semantic** difference is that `Escalation events` gives you a bit more flexibility in modeling a business activity. Not everything that goes wrong during a process is an error. Sometimes, things just don't go quickly enough or there is a non-business critical piece of information that the parent process should know about.

[[image: OMG's definition of BPMN]][https://www.omg.org/spec/BPMN/2.0/]